# prevent index out of bounds with #each_index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

if i was going to do something like this

```
array.each_index do |i|
  if array[i] > array[i + i]
    #something
  end
end
```

how do I change this to prevent an index out of bounds?

Comment: compare with length, for example

Comment: External iterator is considered a bad practice in Ruby. Avoid it whenever possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
array.each_cons(2) do |current, nekst|
  if current > nekst
    #something
  end
end
```

or if you need the index, then:

```
array.each_cons(2).with_index do |(current, nekst), i|
  if current > nekst
    #something with i
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array.each_index do |i|
  if array[i + 1] and array[i] > array[i + i]
    #something
  end
end
```